# Aren’t class attributes inherited?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

I have the following python classes:

`parent.py`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
class parent():
    CONSTANT = 10
```

`child.py`

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from parent import parent

class child(parent):
    print(CONSTANT)
    
    def my_method(self):
        print(CONSTANT)
```

But `child` cannot access `CONSTANT`.

Why doesn’t that work? Is there a way to access the parent’s class attributes (without transforming them all into instance attributes…)

Comment: You will need to read up on how methods work in Python – that needs to be `def my_method(self):` so you have a reference to the instance, and then you'll want `print(self.CONSTANT)`.

Comment: in `my_method` you just have to use `self.CONSTANT` not just `CONSTANT`.

Comment: @AKX I’m losing my mind, I believe I tried print(self.CONSTANT) and it gave me a NameError, but it seems to work now 

Comment: Ah I remember what was the problem, I was writing class attributes in `child`, so no `self` keyword there… But I guess I could just use `parent.CONSTANT` :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It already inherited that. Test it without that print line(I've put both in a module, but that doesn't matter the error is from something else, I'm gonna talk about it next):

```py
class parent:
    CONSTANT = 10

class child(parent):
    pass

print(child.CONSTANT)  # 10
```

But why it throws `NameError: name 'CONSTANT' is not defined` in your example?

`class` keyword in Python is used to create classes which are instances of type `type`. In it's simplified version, it does the following:

1. Python creates a namespace(an empty dictionary basically) and executes the body of the class in that namespace so that it will be populated with all methods and attributes and so on...
2. Then calls the **three-arguments** form of [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). The result of this call is your class which is then assign to a symbol which is the name of your class.

The point is when the body of the class is being executed, it doesn't know anything about the parent namespace , likewise it doesn't know what is `CONSTANT`. So `print(CONSTANT)` is gonna throw a NameError exception.

regarding your comment: Since you already inherited that value, you can access it through both the instance and the class. both work:

```py
class parent:
    CONSTANT = 10

class child(parent):
    def regular_method(self):
        print(self.CONSTANT)
        print(self.__class__.CONSTANT)
        print(super().CONSTANT)

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        print(cls.CONSTANT)

obj = child()
obj.regular_method()
obj.class_method()
```

Comment: I’ve modified `child.py` a bit: I’d like to use the parent’s constant in the child’s methods

Comment: Nit: Not the global namespace, nor `parent`'s namespace.

Comment: @AKX oh, why did I say global, I was talking about parents :) thanks for fixing typo

Answer (score 2):

They are inherited.

```
class parent:
    CONSTANT = 10

class child(parent):
    pass

print(child.CONSTANT) # 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You should encase your `print` into [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod) and reference *attribute* of class rather than global variable, consider following simple example

```
class Parent:
   CONSTANT = 10
class Child(Parent):
   @classmethod
   def print_constant(cls):
       print(cls.CONSTANT)
Child.print_constant()
```

gives output

```
10
```

Comment: Doesn't need to be a classmethod – a regular method with `self.CONSTANT` would work fine.